# Selecting the rows if and only if that value contained in the row/s fulfill an condition

Tags: mysql

I want to select all the rows which are contained in the rows and musst have tinyint=1.

For ex.

```
Number bool
1111       0
1112       1
1113       0
1113       1
1114       1
1114       1
```

I want to select the rows with Table.Number 1112 and 1114 because the value of tinyint is 1 in all rows where the value of 1112/1114 is.

Comment: Are you aware of SQL's `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @Ven Of course, where clause alone will not work because Select Number from Table where Numer = x And bool = 1, Where x is any  Number will also give me 1113, which i dont need because when Number is 1113, bool is not 1 all the time.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, the count of values and the sum of those values are the same.

```
SELECT num
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY num
HAVING COUNT(bool) = SUM(bool);
```